# Amazon Polly Client works with arbitrary keys?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-polly

I have an app that works perfectly. It has dialog for accepting the AccessKey and SecretKey that are passed into AmazonPolyClient constructor.

```
mAmazonPollyClient = new AmazonPollyClient(accessKey, secretKey, mRegionEndpoint);
            mAmazonPollyConfig = new AmazonPollyConfig()
            {
                //RegionEndpoint = mRegionEndpoint,
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), // Set the custom timeout
                ReadWriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) // Set the custom timeout for read/write operations

            };
```

When I intentionally corrupt the keys before passing them to the constructor. The Polly still works fine and generate audio.
Is that because I have paid AWS account? (Should be completely opposite).
Any ideas?

Comment: 'generate audio'- what action is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When initializing AmazonPolyClient no calls are made to the service. But attempting to make any API call like getting the voices will result in 403 return code (Forbidden).

Comment: While make sense it is not answering the question as asked: " The Polly still works fine and generate audio." which seem to be opposite of "result in 403". You may want to have stern look into mirror to figure out which one of you ... misinforming the public :).

Comment: My only explanation is that the correct keys were in some sort of cache... while my first observation was that incorrect keys were delivered into the constructor... My answer is the result of debugging - that caused getting exception - after the fix everything worked...